# Real embryo pictures: How different zones(speeman organizer, marginal zones...) are known?

Tags: development, embryology

In many textbook, figures of embryo are drawn,but in reality how biologist know which zone is this one of  an embryo in gastrulation stade? Except the dorsal lip here i can't localize other thing.[image]